# Android: How to set secondary icon of notification?

Tags: android, notifications

So, Anybody know how to set Secondary Icon in notification:

[image]

Have how to set small icon and large icon by doc, but I can't found how to set secondary icon?

**EDIT:** After answer this question I understand where moved secondary[small icon] on Lollipop:

[image]

Comment: @Shabbir I don't know small icon as secondary icon, after answer "manishkumar" I understand it is, this question not duplicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_logo).setContentTitle(title).setContentText(message).setAutoCancel(true);
```

`setSmallIcon` is what you are looking for

Comment: Yes, you right @manishkumar, this icon moved to another place on Lollipop, I will be accept your answer thanks!

Comment: can it be hard coded in `ApplicationManifest.xml` and also same question for the large icon (the avatar in the example)